# Can anyone provide a reference to the destruction of Kabah?

Tags: kaabah, end-times

Can anyone provide a reference to Hadith that mentions the destruction of Kabah by Dhul-Suwayqatayn, the king of Abyssinia after the death of Isa (AS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Juynboll's *Encyclopedia of Canonical Hadith*, "...on the authority of Ziyad b. Sa'd -- Zuhri -- Sa'id b. al-Musayyab -- Abu Hurayra, who related the Prophet's words:

> The Ka'ba will be destroyed by the spindle-legged man from al-Habasha (i.e., Abyssinia)

Juynboll traces the common link for the hadith back to Sufyan b. 'Uyayna, and goes on to say that this destruction must necessarily occur **after** there are no more people on Earth who call on God's name.

One of the *isnads* for this hadith describes the Prophet having a vision in which "a small, bald figure with distorted hands...bashes away at the House of God with his iron shovel and pickaxe, stripping off its ornaments and coverings."

***Edit***: These are references from sunnah.com; I haven't yet figured out how to read the references in Juynboll's encyclopedia.

Sahih [Muslim 2909 a](http://sunnah.com/muslim/54/71), Book 54, Hadith 71

Sunan [an-Nasa'i 2904](http://sunnah.com/urn/1129140), Book 24, Hadith 0

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know the reference number and which book?

Comment: I'm still learning how to read the confusing references in Juynboll's book. I went to sunnah.com and found the hadith in a couple of places, and I've copied those references into my answer.

Comment: @Ahmed You should note that kaaba has been destroyed before:
https://www.quora.com/Has-the-Kaaba-ever-been-destroyed-by-human

Also the leader of ISIS have called for its destruction